# Fetching Client IP's Client Sided

Tags: java, sockets

Is it possible to fetch the IP addresses of connected clients to a server from the client side?  I know it's possible server sided, but is it client sided?

Note: I'm talking about server-client connection using a basic Socket.

Comment: I am thinking Only and only if server agrees to provide the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only if the server purposely provides that list.

Otherwise, it is not possible to get any information of other clients connected to a server you are connected to (this, of course, applies to Java, but can also be understood as a general concept of networking -- in the context of peer to peer, client/server, sockets).

Comment: Thank you, makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

Not without a script or program on the client end of the socket having code to retrieve it (e.g. Javascript on a web page).  You cannot tell this strictly from the server side.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking with your server, and only server talks with other clients directly. So only server can send you clients ip addresses.

So, this is possible, but must be implemented on server.